# Computed Column Showing Blank Value - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum, calculated-columns, isnull, qsqlquery

I have a table where i want different columns to be calculated and store the computed result in another column. I am using the simple computed column option to sum out those columns. But the problem is that the computed column is not showin any result. this is the parameter i am using in computed column field.

```
[mo1]+[mo2]+[mo3]+[mo4]+[mo5]+[mo6]+[mo7]+[mo8]+[mo9]+[mo10]
```

P.S i have linked this table in Ms. Access form.

Comment: Looks like a high likelihood that some normalization is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle `NULL`:

```
ISNULL(mo1,0) + ISNULL(mo2, 0) + ...
```

Or if it is text then you could use `CONCAT`:

```
CONCAT(mo1, mo2, mo3, ..., mo10)
```